# How to separate text file complex and write to DataTable C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text, datatable

I have a text file with content complex. I want to parse it to DataTable. The condition of breaking content and writing to DataTable is quite hard. I try hard more time, but it's not working. So, if you have any advice for this, can you advise me? Appreciate your answer. The content of the text file is as below:

```
2023-03-14|Question|INFO |Comment: Can you ask me?
2023-03-14|A1B13|LOG|Comment: A1B13 W 2 
<Tag
>.
2023-03-14|Answer|INFO |Comment: OK, go ahead.
2023-03-14|A1B14|LOG|Comment: A1B14 2 
<Tag
  <Tag KeyID>
  <Tag
    <Type "Html">
  >
>.
```

the result DataTable expect should be this

[image]

I try with this below, and it can find break condition, but the content merge not correct

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    string date_time = "";
    string mess_start = "";
    string mess_end = "";
    bool flag = false;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(System.String));
    dt.Columns.Add("Content", typeof(System.String));
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            mess_end += line + "\n";
        }
        string[] items = line.Split('|');
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(items[i], @"^A([1-9]\d?)B([1-9]\d?)$"))
            {
                date_time = items[0];
                mess_start = items[3].Substring(9) + "\n";
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mess_end != "")
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { date_time, mess_start + mess_end });
    }
```

I should change something else for that.

Comment: [`new Regex(@"^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.+?(?=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|\z))", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(test)
.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Select(s => s.Split('|')).Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a[1], @"^A([1-9]\d?)B([1-9]\d?)$")).Select(a => new object[] { a[0], a[3]})`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ULhd20)

Comment: omg, really Selvin ? this way look like very crazy, not recommend for this trick.

Comment: working fine ... you can even use `new Regex(@"^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\|A(?:[1-9]\d?)B(?:[1-9]\d?)\|(?:[^\|]+)\|(.+?)(?:(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})|\z)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(test)
.Cast<Match>().Select(m => new object[] { m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value })`  making your code [almost one-liner](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UAR30L) ... basically all is done by [regex](https://regex101.com/r/vD6Oih/1)

Comment: also your match regex could be simple [`A\d+B\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/CWFg4L/1) so it would work even for `A(at least one digit)B(at least one digit)` ... btw you already: 1. loaded whole file to memory 2. using a regex ... then why not to use a regex to done all